# What is the proper way to interrupt a client thread while it's calling an EJB method?

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb, interrupted-exception

I have a java client which is managing its server calls in new threads to prevent the GUI from freezing.

Even if this is prevented in many places, it is possible that the method will be called again on the same model, for example with different parameters. In such case, I obviously want the newest call, with the most up to date parameters, to be the one "succeeding" and displaying its results.

I have a system which is keeping track of the previously launched Thread, and interrupts it before launching the new one (`Thread.interrupt()`). The other methods are then checking if they are running in a non-interrupted thread (using `if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`) before firing the new results to the GUI elements.

This structure was working with a previous connector to the server, as I was the only one checking the interrupt flag on the process. My problem is that I'm now using EJB method calls in the client, and they react badly to the interrupted thread. Interrupting the Thread during an EJB call will trigger a `RuntimeException` which is including an `InterruptedException`. And it doesn't seem like a normal thing to happen.

Obviously I could catch RuntimeExceptions in every server call and check their cause for the interrupt, but it doesn't seem very "clean".

**My question is: what can I do in such context? What is the proper way to interrupt a Thread running an EJB method call?**

Comment: Does it matter that the newly-obsolete call to the EJB completes? Or do you really need to actually stop processing on the EJB side?

Comment: @Rich - It doesn't really matter. Stopping it would be better, but would require a much bigger structure on the server side, with messaging, most likely. For this question I only focus on the client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the existing architecture, I finally went with catching the RuntimeException from each server call, in such form:

```
try {
    return getEJBService().getServiceResult(param, param, param);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    Throwable cause = e.getCause();
    if (cause instanceof InterruptedException)
        throw (InterruptedException)cause;
    else
        throw e;
}
```

It's not really pretty, but at least it allows me to act according to the interruption with my current model.

In the ideal world, one should rather go with [one of the solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231302/what-is-the-proper-way-to-interrupt-a-client-thread-while-its-calling-an-ejb-met/5231857#5231857) given by [Rich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68283/rich).

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you don't mind the obsolete EJB call continuing on the server, why not allow the calling thread to terminate 'naturally' but to discard the result because its call has been superceded by another thread? I don't have time to provide a sample implementation, but you may find that you get some mileage with `Future`s and the related Java concurrency classes.

**Edit**

Further to this, you may find something like this would do the trick, but it feels hacky to me and I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.

On the calling thread (perhaps the onclick method of a button):

```
AsynchronousResultManager.registerRequest("UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER", runnableExecuteRequest);
```

The `registerRequest` would do something like:

```
registerClick(String id, Runnable execution) {
    AtomicReference ref = executions.get(id); //executions is a Map<String, AtomicReference> created as a a computing map by Guava MapMaker
    execution.setReference(ref); //so that the Runnable has a reference to it later
    ref.set(execution); //this will overwrite an existing reference to a previous invocation.
    //here you need to actually kick off your thread in whatever way works best for you
}
```

The `runnable` that executes the request would be a subclass of:

```
public abstract class RequestRunnable implements Runnable {

    private AtomicReference ref;

    public void run() {
        doRunInternal(); //actually go off and do the request to the J2EE server
        if (this == ref.get()) { //ie if the current runnable is the same as in the reference, we can proceed to actually dispatch the result
            dispatchResult(); //this method would do something like add a runnable to the SwingWorkerThread
        }
    }

    protected abstract void doRunInternal();
    protected abstract void dispatchResult();

    public void setReference(AtomicReference ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

}
```

This will probably crash and burn, but hopefully it points you down a line of enquiry...

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. Future (and the concurrent package) would probably be the way to go, but the current system is too widely used in the program to refactor all of it, as it is. I agree that it would be the best way to handle this.

Comment: About the second example, my current implementation is in fact an abstract class dealing with the threading, while the actual work is in one abstract method which is implemented by my models. My problem there is that I have sub models which are not relying on the same framework, and which are dealing with the "dispatchResult" part on their own. As such, it would require some refactoring as well to go this way (though less than the first solution).

Answer (score 0):

To stop a thread you need to perform 2 sort of actions :

- if the thread is waiting for a blocking operation (IO, network, lock...) you need to interupt it. An InterruptedException will be thrown giving the running code the opportunity to catch the exception and to halt in a proper way.
- If the thread is just doing some processing, Thread.interrupt() will not help. No exception will be thrown and the thread will simply continue it's processing. The processing code will need to check on a regular basis that you still want the process to continue.

In any case, to do it properly, you need that the code that is run by your thread that you want to stop deal with the both cases. No silver bullet here.

Comment: The second case I'm covering already, as I'm checking between each heavy processing if the Thread is interrupted, as well as before/after a server call. For the first point, however, calling the interrupt will trigger a RuntimeException from the EJB call. My problem is not really about knowing when I'm interrupted, I was managing that already and stopping any further processing on the Thread. My issue really lies with the "new" exception thrown by the EJB.